# Better way to search for unaccepted posts

Tags: support, search, accepted-answer

I like to make sure I am not person that:

1. Ask questions
2. Gets answers
3. Benefits from answers
4. Never accepts an answer

However I also dont like to accept right away, so that I am not adding to FGIW
problem. The problem comes with actually finding post of mine that I have not
accepted. Currently I use this type search:

```
user:me hasaccepted:no answers:1
```

but this does not quite get me all the way. The issue is that some of these
result either have mediocre or downright bad answers, that I have subsequently
ignored or downvoted.

Yet these questions persist in my search results. I would like to exclude them.
I thought of 2 options but neither panned out:

1. Add all of my questions with "bad" answers to favorites, then search
   `-infavorites:mine`. This failed because it just thinks that is a search term
   rather than an operator.
2. Convert all my questions with "bad" answer to Wiki, then I could just search
   `wiki:no`. This could work but I would have to flag all of them, as you cant
   convert your own questions.

Help? The search system is making it hard for me to do "The Right Thing", and
making it easier for me to just leave potential good answers unaccepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your criteria are subjective no query can get you 100% of the way there, but here are two things you can do to get closer to what you want.

First, replace `answers:1` with `isanswered:yes`, which checks for questions with positive score.  That won't filter out answers *you* downvoted but enough other people upvoted, but it'll at least exclude the negative-scoring posts.

Second, you can use time ranges to reduce the result set and look at everything.  If you search for `user:me is:q hasaccepted:no lastactive:2017`, you'll get all your questions that had some activity in that year -- most importantly, new answers and edits.  Look through them, decide, and then don't revisit that year for a while or unless you get a notification about a new answer.  (You can also narrow it down to a month at a time if that's easier for you.)

Beyond that, you'll need to use [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com), which lets you write a SQL query.  If what you want can be expressed in SQL, that's probably your best bet.  If you aren't familiar with SEDE, check out the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) that I wrote.

Neither search nor SEDE lets you search for posts you have (or haven't) voted on, so you can't filter out things you've downvoted.

Comment: actually this works! i went with `lastactive:2018-10..` but thanks!

Comment: Oh that's a good idea -- that way you get answers that have been edited, which might change your assessment of them.  Yes you'll also get edits to the question and hits from answers that were subsequently deleted (like spam), but that's probably not too much noise to dig through.  I'll edit to add your suggestion.